# Select ng-model change but html stay stills, Ipad safari mobile 7.0

Tags: angularjs, ipad, mobile, safari

I got one problem in Ipad safari mobile 7.0 that ng-model change but it doesn't bind to HTML. This code will illustrate more:

```
<select ng-model="bookingFromTime" ng-change="changeBookingTime()"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option> </select>

$scope.changeBookingTime = function(){ 
  if( $scope.bookingFromTime == 2) { 
      $scope.bookingFromTime = 3; 
  } 
}
```

In another web browsers in PC or even ipad mobile safari 8.+ . When I select 2 it will change to 3 in html but in Ipad Safari 7.0 it stays the same value 2 in html. So how could I fix that bug in ipad safari 7.0?

Comment: Which version of angular are you using?

Comment: Hi, I am using angular version 1.3.16.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using the latest AngularJS code base because it seems like you may be hitting the bug [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5192)

Comment: Hi, I am using angular version 1.3.16.

Comment: Well I also try with new version for 1.4.1 but no luck :(